# Firebase Realtime Database REST API with Android Firebase Authentication and password provider getting 401's unauthorized with standard security rule

Tags: android, rest, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am unable to do a GET using a pretty standard Retrofit request using Firebase Realtime Database REST API.  When I turn the security rules off i.e. `.read = true` it works.  Here is the code for the rest request.

Here is the security rules:

```
   "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth!=null && auth.uid===$uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid !=null",
   }
```

Here is the code for the rest request.

```
 @GET("/users/{path}.json?")
    suspend fun getUser(@Path("path") uidpath : String, @Query("uid") uid : String,  @Query("auth") authToken: String) : User?
```

I should note the first parameter, the 'Path' is being hardcoded to the resource URI endpoint I am testing with.  By this I mean in my realtime database it looks like this: `/users/-NZEVfV5SDWAdQEy9EOW`.

In my request I have both the UID & the authtoken.  I am also unable to get this working with curl requests.  I either get 'permission denied' or unauthorized.  I'm assuming permission denied is when you use an invalid token.  If I use a read rule with "auth != null" it works and with ".read": "auth.uid !=null" works.

My best guess it has something to do with how I am generating the URL.  The documentation is pretty sketchy and incomplete.

Here is the logged out URLs.

```
https://posterpal-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users/-NZEVfV5SDWAdQEy9EOW.json?&uid=IrylAw30oKUmtvH6EJNPkPn4sdr1
&auth=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImY5N2U3ZWVlY2YwMWM4MDhiZjRhYjkzOTczNDBiZmIyOTgyZTg0NzUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vcG9zdGVycGFsIiwiYXVkIjoicG9zdGVycGFsIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjg4MTkyNjMxLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiSXJ5bEF3MzBvS1VtdHZINkVKTlBrUG40c2RyMSIsInN1YiI6IklyeWxBdzMwb0tVbXR2SDZFSk5Qa1BuNHNkcjEiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODgxOTI2MzEsImV4cCI6MTY4ODE5NjIzMSwiZW1haWwiOiI2bmp4cXptdGlAcWlvdHQuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7ImVtYWlsIjpbIjZuanhxem10aUBxaW90dC5jb20iXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9fQ.Xd5IPiBK9U4in-DWKNs-neFRVax1K_L1F9xTjjGhHEbfD2h3IjkBK8rcL4ndiwohoBuyOJxHU4-pFtlFqSJfC-qjnA7zsSemad_2LHvFFKJEwTE4UlYxhmrZVOjmKkpa-JPs9BUvuN_bo2acVfAZ_Jox-2xmgJCKLXezRBGgKQa11E2oYCvPeRafy6mHqbZ-0kT8hTwyNRN_WCn6P_EDkQTT08ylgRa02COcgRV8A9M6lvQ5SK2LRCGxuwOoceuFAW7voGaXjdkede4AlDxsE-WWHayFF3V3PeVumKcGnTo0YBrEvS1iWVqBYoHorddAitJAIgEkF81YCk7V0Y7Ktw
```

I tried auth.uid=$uid but that doesn't work and the period messes up the URL.

If there is a way to switch to the Google OAuth 2.0 credential flow I might do it, as the documentation suggests there are different flows and different token requirements.

Here is the documentation I'm working from:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth